# php mysql search start & end dates fields for todays date if it falls inside range

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table for events that has start and stop dates.
id like to be able to print todays events out in a list(and the next 3 days too) for all events not more then 25.
so if a event was started last week and ends a week from now it would print todays, tomorrows, and next day in the list. if event starts tomorrow it would print **NOT** todays,would print tomorrows and next day. if a event started a week ago and ends tomorrow it print today,tomorrow and **NOT** next day

how do i get mysql via php to find if today falls in the range of start and stop dates fields please.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `iwia_events` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `event_location` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_price` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_url` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_start` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `event_stop` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `event_text` text,
  `extra_info` text,
  `active` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `categories` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want start date to be less than today and end date to be greater than today isnt it?

```
SELECT * FROM iwia_events WHERE event_start< now() AND event_stop > now()
```

SQL fiddle example with your data structure here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee5dd/1/0

Comment: wouldn't that print all events. i need it to be a range ie aug 28 is today aug 21 is event start date and event end date is aug 31 - i need to be able to say ok aug 21 is in that range we have a match whats the event info - i need it to look at my table fields of start and end to see if its that range

Comment: Yes that would select all records that have a start date before today (21 Aug is before today) and ends after today (31 Aug is after today)

Comment: im looking to fall in the range of my table fields event_start and enevt_stop NOT ALL records that are before today and after today

Comment: Please test my condition, anything that starts before today and ends after today would be in range today, I believe you want currently active events, which is exactly what my query will give you

Comment: Please see example here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee5dd/1/0, I have a future event, old event and current event and my query selects only current event

Comment: wow didnt know there was a sqlfiddle and thats what im looking for thank you

Comment: Glad that I could help :) I guess you can upvote if it helped you... sorry to ask but just trying to find if there is any part of the question left unanswered